# I tried installing android studio 4.0 multiple times, but there is no sdkmanager.bat

Tags: android, sdk, unreal-engine5, android-sdk-manager

I've tried installing android studio 4.0 to use with Unreal Engine AR, but there is no sdkmanager.bat at C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk. I've also tried checking the "tools" or "bin" directory, but I've had no luck. can someone help me please?

I've tried reinstalling android 4.0 multiple times. I've deleted all the files located in AppData folder and reinstalling it as well. I've also tried checking the "tools" or "bin" directory, but I've had no luck. can someone help me please?